# Creating an ecommerce product image carousel with 2 images in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've searched Google for a Bootstrap snippet to be able to display two images when clicking a nav bar as displayed in the image below but I can't find any examples. Do you have any examples of how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a javascript library called "[lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/)" that did the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/hqt7vbeu/

JS (change "item" to 2):

```
$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
    gallery: true,
    item: 2,
    loop: true,
    slideMargin: 0,
    thumbItem: 9
});
```